How to Implement Cross-Referencing between the content in Private S3 Bucket Using CloudFront and Signed Cookies
I have a web application set up with a private S3 bucket and CloudFront to deliver the content efficiently. Within the S3 bucket, I've organized static web pages into different projects, each contained within its respective folder. This structure ensures better organization and management of the content.
└── S3 bucket root/
    ├── project A/
    │   ├── css files
    │   ├── js files
    │   └── index.html
    ├── project B/
    │   ├── css files 
    │   ├── js files
    │   └── index.html  
    └── ... 

Currently, I'm utilizing CloudFront signed cookies to control access to the content based on folder path such as "root/project A" or "root/project B", and these signed cookies are generated from within my web application. This approach allows me to restrict access to the static content solely through my web application. Although I haven't enabled static hosting in the S3 bucket, the static web pages render perfectly in the browser.
Now, I aim to implement cross-referencing between projects within the S3 bucket. Specifically, I want to insert a href link pointing to index.html of project B into the index.html of project A. This way, when a user clicks on the provided link in the index.html(project A), they should be redirected to project B and able to view its static content.
Given that my S3 bucket is private and structured by folders, each project remains isolated and protected. Access to these projects is exclusively through CloudFront using signed cookies. I've experimented with various approaches, including leveraging Lambda@Edge functions in both viewer and origin requests, to dynamically generate the required signed cookies when a user interacts with an href link. However, thus far, I haven't been successful in implementing this functionality. It's possible that there are nuances in the implementation that I haven't fully grasped yet, as I'm still getting acquainted with this aspect of the setup.
And I don't want to group project A and project B under the same folder in the S3 bucket. This decision stems from my desire to maintain a dedicated folder structure for each project. By organizing projects into separate folders, I can ensure clarity and organization, making it easier to manage and navigate through the content. Additionally, maintaining distinct folder structures allows for better scalability and flexibility, as each project can evolve independently without interference from others.
Therefore, I want to get help from someone here and hope to hear your opinion on how to implement this? Thanks
